# Rest API Salesforce with Certificate

Tags: apex, api, rest, authentication

I have a Rest API Service:

```
@HttpPost
    global static String actualizarAveriaIngenico(String numorden_stu, String numproceso_mant,
        String estado_averia, String nombre_tecnico, String tipo_intervencion, Date fecha_levantamiento_incidencia) {
        System.debug('**** actualizarAveriaIngenico INI');

        String responseJsonString = '';
        if(numproceso_mant != null && numproceso_mant != ''){
            List<Case> listCases = new List<Case>([Select Id, TXT_Estado_averia__c, TXT_ID_averia__c, TXT_Tipo_de_intervencion__c,
                                                    Status, PL_Motivo__c, PL_Escalado__c, CB_Parada_SLA__c,
                                                    DATE_Fecha_reactivacion_SLA__c, TXT_Nombre_completo_del_tecnico__c
                                                    From Case 
                                                    Where TXT_ID_averia__c =: numproceso_mant]);

            Case caso = listCases.get(0);
            if (caso != null){
                if(estado_averia.equals('Cerrada - OK') || estado_averia.equals('Cerrada - KO')){
                    caso.TXT_Estado_averia__c = estado_averia;
                    caso.Status = 'Cerrado';
                    if (caso.PL_Motivo__c == null){
                        caso.PL_Motivo__c = '';
                        //Falta por indicar un motivo. No es necesario si este ya esta relleno
                    }
                    caso.PL_Escalado__c = 'Nivel 1';
                    //Se deberia enviar un correo al cliente - A quien seria?
                } else if(estado_averia.equals('Cerrada - Incidencia')){
                    caso.TXT_Estado_averia__c = estado_averia;
                    caso.CB_Parada_SLA__c = true;
                    caso.DATE_Fecha_reactivacion_SLA__c = fecha_levantamiento_incidencia;
                    //Se debe evitar la llamada al WS Parada de SLA
                } else {
                    caso.TXT_Estado_averia__c = estado_averia;
                    caso.DATE_Fecha_reactivacion_SLA__c = fecha_levantamiento_incidencia;
                }

                caso.TXT_Nombre_completo_del_tecnico__c = nombre_tecnico;
                caso.TXT_Tipo_de_intervencion__c = tipo_intervencion;

                String codigo = '0';
                String descripcion = '';

                try{
                    update caso;
                }catch(DmlException e){
                    codigo = '-1';
                    descripcion = e.getMessage();
                }

                //Generamos el JSON de respuesta
                responseJsonString = processResponse(codigo, descripcion);
                System.debug('**** responseJsonString - Existe ID averia ' + responseJsonString);
            } else {
                //Generamos el JSON de respuesta
                responseJsonString = processResponse('-1', 'No existe ningun caso asociado a este ID de averia');
                System.debug('**** responseJsonString - No existe ID averia ' + responseJsonString);
            }

            System.debug('**** actualizarAveriaIngenico END');
        } else {
            System.debug('**** responseJsonString - numproceso_mant incorrecto ' + responseJsonString);
            responseJsonString = processResponse('-1', 'No se ha ofrecido un numproceso_mant correcto');
        }

        return responseJsonString;
    }
```

I also created a Connected App.

My doubt is about the authentication flow that i should use. The client does not want use username and password. They want a Certificate server to server.

I investigate that method of authentication and there are two options.

- OAuth 2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow
- OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow

What is the best option in my case? 
And other question i have is, how i can check if the client do the request with the correct certificate? Do i need to do this in apex or the connected app do for me when i assign the certificate that i generate previously?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth flow that uses a certification for authorization is JWT. You'd generate a certificate and populate it on the Connected App, then preauthorize Profiles or Permission Sets for the user account the remote system is going to use to authenticate.

Salesforce will validate that the remote system presents a valid JWT authorization that's signed via the certificate that you selected; your Apex class is not required to confirm that authentication step.

Here's the documentation on the [JWT Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5).

The Web Server OAuth flow uses a secret value protected by the server but not a specific certificate for authorization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i understand correctly, the person who will do the request to my rest service need a Salesforce user, or not? I want that client dont need credentials in salesforce to do the request. 
In the other hand, when i generate the certificate and the key, i need to pass it to client? Or the client must generate his own certificate and pass me into the request?
Finally i do not understand the last point: The Web Server OAuth flow uses a secret value protected by the server but not a specific certificate for authorization.

Comment: Yes, they need a Salesforce username, but not a password. The certificate must be pre-shared between you and the client.

Comment: Web Server OAuth just doesn't use a certificate to authenticate. It obtains a refresh token via a normal username/password authentication and the web server uses a pre-shared secret value to establish its identity.

Comment: Thanks again. I created the certificate Self-Signed in the Certificate and Key Management setup section. Then i download this .crt file and add it in the connected app. Now i am trying to do the request out of Salesforce from Salesforce but it dont work. Whats the better way to do that request to test if my service provide an access token for later do request to my rest api?

Comment: I always receive this error:

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "invalid assertion"
}

I am trying to do with postman but i dont know how i can pass the certificate that a previous download